# Rails 5 is always checking for MongoDB adapter when I am not even using that Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have just scaffolded a Rails 5 app but the gemfile does not have any Mongodb gem or even the database.yml file does not even have any mongoDB. But when i run 'rails s' command it always outputs an error

**Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mongodb_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.**

Not able to understand how to even debug this as even google search does not point towards any meaningful solution

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Do a full search in your app for mongodb_adapter and see what comes up. It has to be somewhere.

Comment: I am using webstrom ide and have done the search and the online file it comes up  is development.log which due to me trying to load the browser but apart from that it is not there anywhere

Comment: I have also created another new rails app . All i have run is 'rails new testApp' and then 'rails s' to visit localhost:3000 and it reports with the same error

Comment: I have also noticed that if i create a new rails app with skip active record. then the app works. But the moment i comment out  in application.rb require "active_record/railtie" the same error starts appearing.